# How to write the results of a horizontal countif() vertically in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table consisting of more than 450 columns showing the count of insect species in particular regions:

[image: Data table]

I need to present an evaluation table which shows the amount of times the Species_A count is 1 , and in the next row underneath the amount of times the Species_B Count is 1 and in the next row underneath the amount of times the Species_C Count is 1 ..etc for 450 species.

[image: Results Table]

My problem is, that the formula countif(B1:QM1;1) has to be entered manually because when I copy the cell formula downwards, excel increases the row reference - but i need the column reference to increase.

For example I need;

```
=countif(B2:B6;1)
=countif(C2:C6;1)
=countif(D2:D6;1)...etc
```

but Excel gives me;

```
=countif(B2:B6;1)
=countif(B3:B7;1)
=countif(B4:B8;1)
```

Transposing is too time consuming and is not an option.

Which would be the simplest formula for increasing the column reference but not the row reference?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` to create an array, then use this array in the `COUNTIF`

```
=COUNTIF((OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,6)),1)
```

This can then be dragged down and will work as intended for the sample given.

`B2` works as the start point, change the 6 to match the number of columns etc.